# Java WebSocket API

Tags: websocket, java-websocket

Is that correctly to have multiple ServerEndpoints in web app? Like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/users")
public class UsersEndPoint{
    //some impl
}

@ServerEndpoint("/users/{userId}")
public class UserEndPoint{
    //some impl
}

@ServerEndpoint("/articles")
public class ArticleEndPoint{
    //some impl
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

(it would be better if you would try before asking..)